# How to search for code within a certain project in bazaar

Tags: bazaar

How to search for code within a certain project in bazaar (e.g. say under https://launchpad.net/~play-developers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [bzr-search](http://launchpad.net/bzr-search) plugin should be able to help

Answer (score 2):

Click on the "Related projects" link, go to https://launchpad.net/play then click on Code link, go to https://code.launchpad.net/play and voila.

Comment: There is a Search text box at the bottom of this page, but the search is not limited to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another alternative is the [bzr-grep](https://launchpad.net/bzr-grep) plugin.

This command searches the specified files and revisions for a given pattern. The pattern is specified as a Python regular expression.